Use multiple features to forecast one variable
I am exploring the forecast of time series and techniques such as LSTM and GRU. I have a doubt about the features that I can use as inputs for the network. The majority of the examples that I've read consider autoregression, using past values of the variable we want to predict to forecast the value, transforming the unsupervised problem into a supervised one, organizing the time series. However, I was thinking about using more variables as inputs. Is this possible in any architecture?
I can think of an example: If we have the following data about the weather, I would like to predict the next temperature values based on all the features.
| Timestamp | humidity | wind velocity | temperature
|    t1     |    h1    |      w1       | temp1
|    t2     |    h2    |      w2       | temp2
|    ...    |    ...   |      ...      | ...

Many thanks in advance for any insight regarding this topic

Yes, you can mix current data with any past data and use any ML model with this data as you usually do with any table data. For example, you can do this:

Extract parts of time-dependent data in separate columns:

Day
Month
Year


Use past values of any feature you have:

past humidity
past wind velocity
past temperature


Use past values for any period you like:

1-2-3-4-...
...days
...weeks
...months
...years


Aggregate data for some periods of the past and use. For example:

mean temperature for a week, month, year, etc.



Use any features you like, but don't "look in to the future". For any timestamp you have to look only in the data of past timestamps.
Then you can use any ML algorithm: LR, XGBOOST, RF, neural networks to predict any of your current features: humidity, wind, temperature. And you need to select really useful features and drop features which is not useful. But you can't predict which features will be helpful before you try it. You have to generate as many features as you can, then try some models and then select useful features, then try your models again.

Sorry If I explained myself wrong. I want to predict the next value of the time series (t+1) based on past values. I want to know if it's possible to predict the temperature value considering the other variables.

@tms Yes, you can predict current temperature using current wind velocity, humidity and past values of temperature, wind velocity, humidity, etc. But if you want to use TS algorithms such as ARIMA (or LSTM), you need to use it separately and add it's prediction, based on past temperature, to other features, and then use any regression method with features, which I described in answer, plus ARIMA prediction. If you can provide some data, I can show you all the process.

Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but I don't have the data at the moment. We still have to capture the samples. My problem is that I usually (in FNNs) treat the inputs as a matrix with the shape (batch, features) to feed the training process. In the case of RNNs, I don't clearly see how to add the time variable.
